# Sculpture identification

Tags: identification

I need to know who they are.
There is no signature or mark on it.
Thanks in advance.

[image][image]

Comment: Care to give a little more information on where these sculptures are from/where they are now?

Comment: These look like consumer collectibles, judging from scale and glass display shelf. They could represent anything from Greek philosophers to Roman Emperors to mythological characters or Gods. (The foremost top resembles some representations of Aristotle)

Comment: These are indeed consumer collectibles, located in a store, nowhere special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! They are a low quality reproduction of:

Aristotle (left)

Thales of Miletus (right)

Apollo (image below)